# Using jquery to copy a portion of a table in the most optimized way

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using JQuery to manipulate a page which I do not have access to modify server-side.  One of the main things I need to do is create a copy of just a sub-section of one of the tables on the page.  More specifically, I need to create 2 tables, one which is a copy of just the first two rows of the table and another which is just the first column.

After optimizing it as far as I could, I'm fairly happy with the performance of the row copy but the column copy is still a bit on the slow side.

I have the following, where sourceTable is the original table and titleColBody is the tbody of a new table created earlier:

```
sourceTable.find("tr").each(function(){
   titleColBody.append(
      $("<tr></tr>").append($(this).children(":first").clone())
   );
});
```

On a table with roughly 50 rows and a huge number of columns, this takes approx. 350ms in IE8.  Not terrible, but I would like to bring this down a little if possible.

**My question is if there is a more efficient way of doing this in JQuery.**

Similarly, I create the copy of the first 2 rows of the table as below.

```
headerTable.find("tbody")
   .append(sourceTable.find("tr:eq(0)").clone())
   .append(sourceTable.find("tr:eq(1)").clone());
```

This is fairly quick, however if there is a better way of doing it I would be happy to hear it.

Any optimization at all would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like this might be a tad bit faster for the columns, this way you'll only grab one resource set instead of grabbing two sets (one for the TRs and then one for the child TDs):

```
sourceTable.find("tr > td:first-child").each(function(){
    titleColBody.append($("<tr></tr>").append($(this).clone()));
});
```

Also on another note, if the "titleColBody" is a pointer to a DOM object that causes the browser to have to render the page when it's updated, you're better off appending to a documentFragment and then appending that fragment (so the browser only re-renders once).

For instance:

```
var titleCol = document.createDocumentFragment();
sourceTable.find("tr > td:first-child").each(function(){
    titleCol.append($("<tr></tr>").append($(this).clone()));
});
titleColBody.append(titleCol);
```

Comment: @musicinmyhead, 

"tr > td:first" appears to only match the first td of the first tr, as opposed to the first td of every tr.  And oddly enough, takes nearly as long even though it's only matching one element.

The titleColBody only exists in memory at the time this code is run and is later added to the DOM, so if I understand your second suggestion this is not an issue for me.

Comment: @kingjiv, sorry about that, should have been :first-child. I rarely use the :first or :first-child selectors so I forgot that :first only matches the first element it finds. And yeah, don't worry about the second suggestion then since your titleColBody isn't referencing a pre-existing DOM element.

Comment: @musicinmyhead, that doesn't work either.  In fact, I think that would try to get the first child of the td element which is not right.  I tried "tr:first-child", thinking that maybe that would give the first child of each tr which would be a td and that doesn't work either.

Comment: @kingjiv, haha dammit sorry again my bad. Using the .is() function solves that problem, I've updated the examples above.

Comment: @musicinmyhead, actually no, that one's on me.  Your last example works perfectly.  My cells were th and not td so it didn't match.  This actually works and cuts the time down below 100ms which is great.  Revert to "td > th:first-child" and I'll accept the answer.

Comment: @musicinmyhead thanks for your help, it's working great.  Would you mind reverting back to "td > th:first-child" so I can accept the answer?